# Dynamic Connection for a Project in SSIS

Tags: parameters, ssis, connection, environment-variables, foreach-loop-container

I have a project and some packages in it.Now I use 3 different servers so I have 3 data flows for each server in each package.These 3 servers in future will be 15 servers so I have to find a way to use dynamic connections so I will have 1 data flow.Scope of my OLE DB connections are project scope and I can't use variables in it when I parameterize it.Now I have a table in one of the servers that includes the serverNames in it named ConnectionTbl.I run an "Execution SQL Task" and put the serverNames in an object variable named ObjConnection.Then I put a "For Each Loop Container" and in Collection for the "ADO Object Source Variable" I put the ObjConnection.Now in mapping variable I can't map the parameter but for a project level connection I need to pass a parameter.So I searched and figured out that there is an environment variable,I've deployed the project and assigned an environment variable to my parameter but some how I need to give this environment variable the values from ConnectionTbl but I can't refer it to that
I don't have any problem in Package Scope connections because with using variables the connection works just fine.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you define your environment variable in windows? something like this: "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=[db here];Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI"

You need to define this environment variable on each environment you work on to connect to the right db/instance.

Comment: @ppijnenburg I guess he is talking about this: [Setup Environment Variables in SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4810/setup-environment-variables-in-sql-server-integration-services/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DTExec command prompt utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/dtexec-utility?view=sql-server-2017) to execute the project and update the Project parameter dynamically.

In your case, try to create a master package and execute the project in Execute Process Task.

[image]

```
DTExec /ISSERVER "\SSISDB\folderB\Integration Services Project17\Package.dtsx" /SERVER "." /Envreference 2 /Par "$Project::ProjectParameter(Int32)";1 /Par "Parameter(Int32)";21 /Par "CM.sqlcldb2.SSIS_repro.InitialCatalog";ssisdb /Par "$ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean)";True
```